# Getting RE(SIGSEGV) in online ide

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime, segmentation-fault

There are some constraints:
1≤T≤100 
the sum of N over all test cases does not exceed 10^7
1≤C≤10^9

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;



bool comp_func(int x,int y)
{
return x>=y;
}
vector<int> primeFac(int n)
{
vector<int> result;
while (n%2 == 0)
{
    result.push_back(2);
    n = n/2;
}

// n must be odd at this point.  So we can skip
// one element (Note i = i +2)
for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2)
{
    // While i divides n, print i and divide n
    while (n%i == 0)
    {
        result.push_back(i);
        n = n/i;
    }
}

// This condition is to handle the case when n
// is a prime number greater than 2
if (n > 2)
    result.push_back(n);
return result;
}

int main()
{
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
int t;cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
    int n,c;cin>>n>>c;
    vector<int> d;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        d.push_back(i);
    if(c==1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<d[i]+1<<" ";
    }
    else{
        vector<int> prime_fac=primeFac(c);
        sort(prime_fac.begin(),prime_fac.end());
        if(prime_fac.size()<n)
        {
            int c_2=count(prime_fac.begin(),prime_fac.end(),2);
            int c_3=count(prime_fac.begin(),prime_fac.end(),3);

            if(c_2!=0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<c_3;i++)
                {
                    d[i]+=3;
                }
                int pos=0;
                for(pos=c_3;pos<n-(prime_fac.size()-c_3-c_2);pos++)
                {
                    if(pos<c_3+c_2)
                        d[pos]+=2;
                    else
                        d[pos]+=1;
                }
                for(int i=c_2+c_3;i<prime_fac.size();i++)
                {
                    d[pos++]+=prime_fac[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sort(prime_fac.begin(),prime_fac.end(),comp_func);
                for(int i=n-1,j=0;i>=0 || j<prime_fac.size();i--,j++)
                {
                    if(j<prime_fac.size())
                        d[i]+=prime_fac[j];
                    else
                        d[i]+=1;
                }
            }

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                cout<<d[i]<<" ";
        }
        else
        {
            while(prime_fac.size()!=n)
            {
                prime_fac[0]*=prime_fac[1];
                prime_fac.erase(prime_fac.begin()+1);
                sort(prime_fac.begin(),prime_fac.end());
            }
            sort(prime_fac.begin(),prime_fac.end());
            vector<int> diff;
            for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
            {
                if(prime_fac[i+1]-prime_fac[i]<=1)
                    diff.push_back(prime_fac[i]);
                else
                {
                    diff.push_back(prime_fac[i]);break;
                }
            }
            int size_dif=diff.size();
            if(prime_fac[n-1]-diff[size_dif-1]<=1)
                diff.push_back(prime_fac[n-1]);
            sort(diff.begin(),diff.end(),comp_func);
            if(diff.size()!=1)
            {   int pos_t=0;
                for(int i=0;i<diff.size();i++)
                {
                    d[i]=diff[i]+i;
                    pos_t++;
                }
                for(int i=pos_t;i<n;i++)
                {
                    d[i]=prime_fac[i]+i;
                }
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                    cout<<d[i]<<" ";
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                    cout<<prime_fac[i]+i<<" ";
            }

        }

    }

    cout<<"\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

The biggest thing I see here is C but that too int can handle so I don't think its a datatype error. The only part am skeptical are loops, but i made sure they are leak proof with conditional statements. If anyone can suggest some changes please do :), I might have made a silly mistake.

Comment: Did you stepping through your code with a debugger? SIGSEGV is a sign of undefined behavior somewhere in your code. For example: out-of-bounds vector element access.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` are a really nasty combination. Including the entire standard library and placing it all in the global namespace can lead to epic bugs when you find your identifiers colliding with stuff in the standard library that you didn't even know existed.

Comment: I didn't used debugger because the code works perfectly fine for values that are small, but large values become difficult to track using debugger.

Comment: @user4581301 I get your point, but still see this https://ideone.com/djPnn3 is getting RE

Comment: This will change nothing (or if it does, you had a bug in finding prime numbers) but it looks like you are going for speed. Look into prime sieving algorithms. The brute force approach you are using is horribly slow.

Comment: The debugger will come to a crashing halt when the program segfaults. This give you an excellent opportunity to investigate the call stack and the contained variables to see what pushed the program over the edge. Another trick is to back up your program and replace all uses of `[]` with `at`. `at` throws an exception if you run a `vector` out of bounds .

Comment: I tried seive already, but it was giving RE for most cases due to O(n) memory space https://ideone.com/p2lqXj and it works only upto 10^7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172635/discussion-between-behl-and-user4581301).